# Android draw paths not starting where I clicked in AVD

Tags: java, android

Im making a basic app to test making paths.

So I got the paths to work, but when I am in the emulator and begin a path it starts the path about inch below from where I clicked.

Besides from the path being a inch off below, it will follow my mouse and make a path but always from a inch below where the mouse is.

This is my code:

```
public class Paths extends Activity {

Path newPath = new Path();
Paint paint = new Paint();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_paths);

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    LinearLayout relative = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawing_view2);
    float x = event.getRawX();
    float y = event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            newPath.moveTo(x, y);
            relative.addView(new DrawView2(relative.getContext(), newPath));
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            newPath.lineTo(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        default:
            return false;
    }
    relative.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

This is the java class that handles the paint and canvas objects.

```
 private final Path path;

 private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public DrawView2(Context context, Path path) {
    super(context);
    int mycolor = Color.parseColor("#6633CC");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setColor(mycolor);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
    this.path = path;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

and my layout file

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawing_view2"                            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#33FF99"
```

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting coordinates with

```
float x = event.getRawX();
float y = event.getRawY();
```

Instead of this, try that:

```
float x = event.getX();
float y = event.getY();
```

Comment: Tried that I am getting the same problem